# Struggling to find the formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been given a set of numbers (13 in total) and have been asked to find the formula. I'm normally pretty good at maths, but this has got me stumped.
Can anyone either find the formula to work out the formula or direct me to a site that would help me please?

Numbers (in order):

1. 595
2. 945
3. 1,501
4. 2,382
5. 3,781
6. 6,002
7. 9,526
8. 15,121
9. 24,002
10. 38,100
11. 60,479
12. 96,003
13. 152,393

Comment: What's the origin of the numbers?  Anything you know about them could be relevant for finding a formula.  Also, what kind of formula are you looking for?  Recursive?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: It's for a levelling system in an MMORPG I'm working on for a client. Each level (first column) is based on the EXP (second column)

Comment: Each number seems to be about one and a half times larger than the previous one.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it didn't match perfectly to what I had and, come level 210, it was completely thrown out of whack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather good fit to $375.07\exp(0.4621n)$, which I found from Excel.

Comment: That is a good fit, nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

The sequence starts with 595 and then applies the procedure consisting of two steps:

1. multiply by $4^{1/3}$.
2. Take the [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceiling_function).

Comment: At least in my Excel version, it is not exact, but much closer than my fit.  The first discrepancy comes at 2382 vs 2383, and it is still within 3 at the end.  As $\log 4^{1/3} \approx 0.462098$ we are very close.

Answer (score 0):

This polynomial goes each of these points and of course always produces an integer: 
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{-37}{31933440}x^{12}+\frac{2599}{26611200}x^{11}-\frac{43219}{14515200}x^{10}+\frac{16769}{207360}x^{9}-\frac{225191}{193536}x^8\\
&\frac{27738947}{2419200}x^7+\frac{-1146782897}{14515200}x^6+\frac{36947483}{96768}x^5-\frac{925537457}{725760}x^4+\frac{742083869}{259200}x^3\\&-\frac{737455591}{184800}x^2+\frac{23240863}{6930}x-669
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes, but the curve doesn't look polynomial.

Comment: How did you guess that :-)

Comment: @RossMillikan I was just trying to produce something that would go through the points and would always produce integers rather than 'be close to' the values given and future integers. Indeed, there should be one more higher term for this so that the function will increase as does the sequence.

Comment: @user72694 I just created an interpolating polynomial for the points given. This was not a guess. As in my previous comment, one more point would be necessary to find a better fit as this function will tend to negative infinity while your sequence will continue to increase.

Comment: @user72694:  I just plotted it.  It looked more exponential than polynomial to me.  I also tried divided differences without success.  One can always put a twelfth degree polynomial through thirteen points, but this one will turn around and go negative for large enough $x$-look at the leading coefficient.  I'm sure that is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @user72694 Are your clients set on this list? Because you should choose an rational exponential function that is 'close' to these integers and use that instead for the necessary leveling up. That way, they have an easy calculation coming out to rational numbers and are still 'close' to the required list.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you guys are talking about, but that formula, whilst confusing as hell, looks interesting. I thought I was alright with maths. You, sirs, humble me! xD